# Want Run Pandas_TA In Python

Tags: pandas-ta

Trying to run pandas_ta in python so that I can walk-through code and make modifications.

I've downloaded code from GitHub.  If I use an environment where pandas_ta not installed, when calling the code, I run into an error message - "pandas_ta distribution was not found and is required by the application".  If I use an environment where I have done a pip install of pandas_ta the program runs but I can't step through the code.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can see pip installed packages going to venv/lib/python3.X/python3.X/site-packages/<package name, ie. ta_pandas>.

This "venv/lib/python3.X/python3.X/site-packages/" is called your Libaray root. The "python3.x" may be different depending on the version of Python that you are running.